# How to remove a page from a books and/or delete a book?

Tags: nodes, 8

I placed a basic page into a book but now want it removed from every book. In the book outline settings I only see a way to move it to another book, I see no option to set it to none. I also don't see a way to delete a book in structure/books.

One option I've considered is uninstalling the book module and reenabling it but I'd rather not lose every book I have because of one page.

Is there a way to remove a page from a book, and/or delete a book without uninstalling the book module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a option to remove the any page from the Book outline. Suppose I have created a basic page and put in a Book outline. Now if I want to remove, click outline as shown in the follwoing image

> [image]

Now, you can see `Remove from book outline` in red in as show in following option. That will remove that Basic page from the book.

> [image]

**Update:**

You can not delete entire book at a once. Why, because Book is just a indexing tool, It is not a content type. Book page is a content type. Book page and Book are two different thing. And it should be that way. Hence, you can delete all nodes of one content type by deleting that content type itself. But, if you are putting some node under book outline, you are not creating a entire group/content type, You are just indexing your node in specific order.

Hence, If you delete any Parent item in book, It shows a message that the `child will be re-ordered automatically`. Hence, you can understand its just a ordering/indexing tool.

Hence, to provide this feature [Book Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/book_delete) module was created. But still it does not have Drupal 8 Version.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Is there a way to delete the specific book entirely?

Comment: I have updated answer and added update on book deletion.